# Aplicar degradado a un canvas en el método onDraw

Tags: android, canvas

Estoy trabajando en Android Studio y quiero realizar un degradado de un canvas en un `onDraw`; éste es el codigo del gameview:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN); //Color fondo
}
```

¿Cómo se puede aplicar el degradado al canvas en el método `onDraw`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo esta solución (el degradado es desde arriba hacia abajo):

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), Color.GREEN, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
    canvas.drawPaint(p);
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Me fue de ayuda! Ahora cambiare los "Color" por el formato rgb que deseo de colores.

Comment: No hay de qué, no olvides marcar la respuesta como válida ;)